# AWS EKS Node Affinity Conflict with Spot Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, spot-instances

I'm running some Flink jobs on my EKS cluster in AWS. I am using spot instances to run these jobs, but am running into a problem with a PVC (EBS volume). I am fairly certain the issue is that the EBS volume only binds to one node in my cluster, and every time the spot instance essentially "restarts", the redeployed pod is not able to bind to the volume again, due to the spot instance having a new IP address.

I can clearly see this happening when the instance "restarts" due to the age of the node being a few minutes, and the Flink application cannot reschedule due to a volume node affinity conflict.

Comment: Are you using an autoscale group with multiple AZs? What are you using to automate the node provisioning?

Comment: I am using node groups with no autoscaling at the moment. I have configured my node group to only provision one spot instance node at any time. My config does use 2 AZs though.

Comment: If you mean managed node groups, those create autoscaling groups. If you're using `cluster-autoscaler`, you need 1 node group per AZ for persistent volumes to work correctly. See: https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/README.md#common-notes-and-gotchas.

Comment: Yeah, I am talking about the managed node groups on EKS. There is no dynamic scaling on my node group though.